# How to access class member by string in C#?

Tags: c#, class, reflection

Is there a way to access member by a string (which is the name)?

E.g. if static code is:

```
classA.x = someFunction(classB.y);
```

but I only have two strings:

```
string x = "x";
string y = "y";
```

I know in JavaScript you can simply do:

```
classA[x] = someFunction(classB[y]);
```

But how to do it in C#?

Also, is it possible to define name by string?

For example:

```
string x = "xxx";
class{
   bool x {get;set}  => means bool xxx {get;set}, since x is a string
}
```

**UPDATE**, to tvanfosson, I cannot get it working, it is:

```
public class classA
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}
public class classB
{
    public int B { get; set; }
}

var propertyB = classB.GetType().GetProperty("B");
var propertyA = classA.GetType().GetProperty("A");
propertyA.SetValue( classA, someFunction( propertyB.GetValue(classB, null) as string ), null );
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

```
 var propertyB = classB.GetType().GetProperty(y);
 var propertyA = classA.GetType().GetProperty(x);

 propertyA.SetValue( classA, someFunction( propertyB.GetValue(classB,null) as Foo ), null );
```

where `Foo` is the type of the parameter that `someFunction` requires.  Note that if `someFunction` takes an `object` you don't need the cast.  If the type is a value type then you'll need to use `(Foo)propertyB.GetValue(classB,null)` to cast it instead.

**I'm assuming that we are working with properties, not fields.  If that's not the case then you can change to use the methods for fields instead of properties, but you probably should switch to using properties instead as fields shouldn't typically be public.**

If the types aren't compatible, i.e., `someFunction` doesn't return the type of `A`'s property or it's not assignable, then you'll need to do a conversion to the proper type.  Similarly if the type of B isn't compatible with the parameter of the function, you'll need to do the same thing.

```
 propetyA.SetValue( classA, someFunction(Convert.ToInt32( propertyB.GetValue(classB,null))).ToString() );
```

Comment: @EricYin I guess I was also assuming that the types were compatible.  If the types aren't compatible then you'll need to transform them to compatible types.  One way would be using `Convert`, assuming a conversion exists.

Comment: Got it worked, thanks. Will it performance very low? Or it's the only solution and no choice anyway

Comment: Slow relative to what? Yes, it will be slower than a simple assignment, but on the bright side it will be faster than writing it all to a file and reading it back out again. :-)