# How to access an object using a methods parameter?

Tags: c#

Noob question here, I am wondering how to access a object using a parameter passed into the method. I have tried this but am getting a identifier expected error.

```
private Boolean checkStates(string button)
{
    if (lastState.Buttons.(button) = padState.Buttons.(button))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the javascript equivalent of what I am trying to do.

```
var object = {'property':'A'};

function getPropVal(prop){
    return object[prop];
}

getPropVal(property);
//output: 'A'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access class member by string in #c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953605/how-to-access-class-member-by-string-in-c)

Comment: In your psudo C# example can you give more of a explanation of what you are trying to accomplish? I think I understand what you want but I am not sure. (Also in your if statement you need to use `==` not `=` to test for equality)

Comment: I am trying to access lastState.Buttons with the value passed to the method for example if A is passed I want to access lastState.Buttons.A

Comment: what is lastState.Buttons?...a collection? if so what type?

Comment: In this case `A` is not an `object`, it is a `property` or `field`.You didn't give us enough information,is it a static field or property ? what is `Buttons`, one object or  some kind of list or container ? I don't think your javascript pseudo code is relevant with this question.If so you can do it with dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `Buttons` are dictionaris of "button" by identifier than you can do:

```
   if (lastState.Buttons[button] == padState.Buttons[button])
```

Notice also `==` (assuming you want to compare, not assign since it is an `if` statement).

If it is collection you can use LINQ `FirstOrDefault`:

```
   var button1 = lastState.Buttons.FirstOrDefault(b => b.SomeProperty == button);
   var button2 = lastState.Buttons.FirstOrDefault(b => b.SomeProperty == button);
   if (button1 != null && button1 == button2)...
```

Note that in both cases `if` compares objects, if you want to check equality by particular property - change conditions accordingly.