# WPF UserControl with ItemsSource pathname property like ComboBox 'SelectedValuePath'

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, path

I have a WPF UserControl wrapper for an ActiveX WinForms UserControl so I can properly utilise MVVM/Bindings without having to manipulate the UI from the view model.

My UserControl has an ItemsSource DependencyProperty (and various others). What I would like now is to implement a 'Path' property in the same way as the ComboBox has a `SelectedValuePath` or `DisplayMemberPath` property in order to make it a standalone module.

Currently:

**XAML**

```
<myControls:MyUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" Title.../>
```

**Relevant Code-behind**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(ItemsSourcePropertyName, typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(ItemsSourcePropertyChanged));
public const string ItemsSourcePropertyName = "ItemsSource";
public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get
    {
        return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }
}
private static void ItemsSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyControl control = (MyControl)sender;

    if (control != null)
    {
        control.PropertyChanged();
    }
}
private void PropertyChanged()
{
    if (ItemsSource is List<MyModel>) //TODO: figure out how to avoid this cast for user input fieldname for the path
    {
        List<MyModel> list = (List<MyModel>)ItemsSource;

        if (m_axHost == null)
        { 
            // Create the interop host control.
            m_axHost = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

            // Create the ActiveX control.
            MyAxControl AXcontrol = new MyAxControl();
            AXcontrol.SetData(list.Select(a=>a.XValue).ToArray(), list.Select(a=>a.YValue).ToArray(), Title, ...);

            // Assign the ActiveX control as the host control's child.
            m_axHost.Child = AXcontrol;

            // Add the interop host control to the Grid 
            // control's collection of child controls. 
            this.axControlHolder.Children.Add(m_axHost);
        }
        else
        {
            MyAxControl AXcontrol = (MyAxControl)m_axHost.Child;
            AXcontrol.ClearData();

            control.SetData(list.Select(a=>a.XValue).ToArray(), list.Select(a=>a.YValue).ToArray(), Title, ...);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like:

```
<myControls:MyUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" XValuePath="XPathname" YValuePath="YPathname" Title.../>
```

and

```
control.SetData(ItemsSource.Select(a=>a."XPathname").ToArray(), ItemsSource.Select(a=>a."YPathname").ToArray(), Title, ...);
```

I assume that I would have to use reflection but I don't really know how to progress forward. How can I use the string pathname to generate the correct data for the UserControl?

All the Google/SO results give me answers for solving my ItemsSource problems (which I don't have) or my DependencyProperty problems (again, pretty sure that mine are working just fine). I want to make my UserControl more flexible for future usability by using user specified Paths for the data in the ItemsSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reflection technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953633/3559976) gives the foundation for the solution:

```
var xValues = (from item in this.ItemsSource
               let property = item.GetType().GetProperty(this.XValuesPath)
               select property.GetValue(item)).ToArray();

var yValues = (from item in this.ItemsSource
               let property = item.GetType().GetProperty(this.YValuesPath)
               select property.GetValue(item)).ToArray();
```

which can then be assigned to the ActiveX control

```
control.SetData(xValues, yValues, Title, ...);
```

If specific types are needed e.g. `double[]` or `DateTime[]` then a cast can be made in the linq statement:

```
DateTime[] xValues = (from item in this.ItemsSource
                      let property = item.GetType().GetProperty(this.XValuesPath)
                      select (DateTime)property.GetValue(item)).ToArray();

double[] yValues = (from item in this.ItemsSource
                    let property = item.GetType().GetProperty(this.YValuesPath)
                    select (double)property.GetValue(item)).ToArray();
```

Checking the cast requires a little more work:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTime[] xValues = (from item in this.ItemsSource
                      let property = item.GetType().GetProperty(this.XValuesPath)
                      let value = property.GetValue(item)
                      let castOK = DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out dt)
                      select castOK ? dt : _defaultDateTimeValue).ToArray();

double d = new double();
double[] yValues = (from item in this.ItemsSource
                    let property = item.GetType().GetProperty(this.YValuesPath)
                    let value = property.GetValue(item)
                    let castOK = double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out d)
                    select castOK ? d : _defaultDoubleValue).ToArray();
```